# Flexbox: 2nd row not aligned to 1st row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 items in a flex container. I want 3 each row. I want the container centered-- by centering the container with justify-content the 4th item in the 2nd row was also centered. So I used a ::after trick to try to correct it, but now the 2nd row is not aligned with the 1st row.

The problem, as I see it, is that the flex container is taking more width than the content items forcing me to center it with justify-content which is causing this issue.

Could this be easier using grid? if so how? I want a simple centered grid of iframe youtube videos, 3 per row with the last row aligned left.

https://codepen.io/k4ir0s/pen/RdeejK

```css
.section-vids ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section-vids ul li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.section-vids ul:after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="media">
      <section class="section-vids">
        <ul>
          <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G1FFWgzk4vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                    <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G1FFWgzk4vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                    <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G1FFWgzk4vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                    <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G1FFWgzk4vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: each flex item has an iframe of width 560px - this makes it 3 in a row not possible in smaller screen widths...

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: center;` does not center the container, it centers the items inside of it. If you remove that from your CSS for the `ul`, I'm seeing exactly what I believe you are describing. You could alternatively use `justify-content: space-between;` or `justify-content: space-evenly;` for similar results.

If you're having issues with it overflowing horizontally (which you shouldn't be) then you can set `max-width: 100%;` on the `ul` and that should be resolved. The trick with the `::after` pseudo element is unneeded.